# Putty remember username

Tags: putty

I'm using Putty to connect to a box using a private key file.

I'd like to type the passphrase every time, but I don't want to type "ubuntu" every time for "login as:"

How can I get putty to remember the username, but not the password?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can simply save the host or ip address field in putty as ubuntu@ipaddr.

Answer (score 32):

The option to enter a username is somewhat hidden in the Connection --> Data tab.
You can save a username in either your default profile or for a specific session.

[image: PuTTY-auto-login username]

Also of interest: the suggestions from <del>http://dag.wiee.rs/blog/content/improving-putty-settings-on-windows</del> (link dead; here's an [archived copy](https://web.archive.org/web/20180315092913/http://dag.wiee.rs/blog/content/improving-putty-settings-on-windows))

Comment: Ofc. it's under 'Data' :D